# How to import Django models in seperate class

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using signals for post-processing data. Because a lot needs to happen, and later I want to run that logic on the background so the user doesn't have to wait for this, I want to run this code in a separate class.

[image]

I want to run the code in my Post Save event
[image]

But I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ActivityDetail' from 'ryf_app.models'
```

The model definitely exists in my models.py file
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: My models.py file doesn't sit in my templates folder. Although, I'm also not able to import anything from that folder.

Comment: It looks like you have a circular import. `gps` is importing from `models`, which is importing from `gps`.

Comment: Note that signals are called synchronously. The view won't continue until the signal finishes. If you want to run a task in the background, then consider a task queue like Celery.

Comment: Ah, so circular won't work at all. Already planned to use something like Celery, but wanted to build the logic first before delaying it. Think I have to come with another plan than to solve this, as writing to my model also needs to be done in the class. So I think I'll go for staging and running a cronjob on the background to process these rows independently.

Comment: You can go for celery | Django-q ; refer: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/

Comment: You can quickly get around the circular import by moving the `import GPS` line inside the `save_activity` method where you use it. However it's better to restructure your models so that you don't have circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a task asynchronously or in the background, you might use task queue like celery. For a broker or cache db there are options for redis, rabbitmq, amazon sqs. Celery have a good documentation with rabbitmq supporting broker. You can follow this link-[here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).